# Select div with class name, that are neighbour to a div of a class name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want an xpath or a direct way to select classes with js/jquery of a specific class name if they have a specific neighbor

Example:

```
<ul>
    <li> 
        <div class ="z"> sample</div>
        <div class ="b"> sample</div>
        <div class ="c"> sample</div>

    </li>
   
    <li> 
        <div class ="a"> sample</div>
        <div class ="b"> sample</div>
        <div class ="c"> sample</div>
    </li>
   
    <li> 
        <div class ="z"> sample</div>
        <div class ="b"> sample</div>
        <div class ="c"> sample</div>
    </li>
   
   <li>
        <div class ="a"> sample</div>
        <div class ="b"> sample</div>
        <div class ="c"> sample</div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

so I want a query that would return `<div class="c">` that are neighbours to  `<div class ="z">` sample only.

The long way I know it would be to select $(".z") then loop on them to get the siblings of class c., but I wonder if there is a path to write instead ".z" to get siblings .c

Comment: Provide an example case and your _long way_. Also take a look at https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: Also research the [Adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator). If you can provide more useful details to your question, such as how you actually want to target the elements and the code you've tried, then we will be able to provide more useful advice.

Comment: I want to return element with className c, if they are neighbour to element with class z.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a click listener on the div element, get its parent (which is the li element) and then get its children. This will return you all three divs in the section

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  let parentLi = $(this).parent();
  console.log($(parentLi).children());
  console.log($(parentLi).find('div'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li> 
        <div class ="z"> sample</div>
        <div class ="b"> sample</div>
        <div class ="c"> sample</div>

    </li>
   
    <li> 
        <div class ="a"> sample</div>
        <div class ="b"> sample</div>
        <div class ="c"> sample</div>
    </li>
   
    <li> 
        <div class ="z"> sample</div>
        <div class ="b"> sample</div>
        <div class ="c"> sample</div>
    </li>
   
   <li>
        <div class ="a"> sample</div>
        <div class ="b"> sample</div>
        <div class ="c"> sample</div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Or, use `prev()` and `next()` to get the neighbours to the clicked div (previous and next element)

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).prev());
  console.log($(this).next());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li> 
        <div class ="z"> sample</div>
        <div class ="b"> sample</div>
        <div class ="c"> sample</div>

    </li>
   
    <li> 
        <div class ="a"> sample</div>
        <div class ="b"> sample</div>
        <div class ="c"> sample</div>
    </li>
   
    <li> 
        <div class ="z"> sample</div>
        <div class ="b"> sample</div>
        <div class ="c"> sample</div>
    </li>
   
   <li>
        <div class ="a"> sample</div>
        <div class ="b"> sample</div>
        <div class ="c"> sample</div>
    </li>

</ul>
```